# phantomjs - running render after loading the page, but loading never fires

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to create a graph-to-png converter with phantomjs, but having a hard time getting it to work. Almost every example I see out there uses some external URL as if all you ever do with it is scraping, and the documentation is terribly lacking.

To test out things, I created a very simple d3 function that adds an `<svg>` tag and a blue circle inside. Looking at other questions on SO and examples, I hooked it to onLoadFinish but that event never triggers.

I'm guessing I need to `open` the page, but `open` only uses a url, which isn't relevant for me (and again, the docs are completely lacking in information. Even when I see something I think might be relevant, my [only](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/reload.html) [choice](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/set-content.html) [is](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/get-page.html) [guesswork](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/go.html). This is [ridiculous](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/event.html) )

Here's my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(); 

var content = '<html>';
content += '<body>';
content += '<h1> test title </h1>';
content += '<div id="graph">';
content += '</div>';
content += '</body></html>';    

page.content = content; 

page.injectJs('lib/d3/d3.min.js');
page.onLoadFinish = function(status) {
    console.log('loading finished'); // this never happens!
    var svg = d3.select('#graph')
                .append('svg')
                .attr({'width': 100, 'height': 100});   

    var circle = svg
        .append('circle')
        .attr({ 'cx': 10, 'cy': 10, 'r': 10, 'fill': 'blue' });   

    page.render('test.png');
    phantom.exit();
};
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just used the interactive shell to check the injection too. It doens't work. It's so weird, it's supposed to return a boolean - so injecting a file that doesn't exist returns `false` alright, but trying a file that does exist results in `{}`. WTF is wrong with this library?? It seems broken all over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [evaluate](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html). That was the function I was looking for. It "evaluates the given function in the context of the web page".

Finally, it's working:

```
page.content = content; 
page.injectJs('lib/d3/d3.min.js');
page.evaluate(function() {
    var svg = d3.select('#graph')
                .append('svg')
                .attr({'width': 100, 'height': 100});   

    var circle = svg
        .append('circle')
        .attr({ 'cx': 10, 'cy': 10, 'r': 10, 'fill': 'blue' });   

    page.render('test.png');
    phantom.exit();
};
```

Comment: Please don't use code tags for emphasis or quotation; code tags are for _code_ (or other verbatim technical stuff).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure I agree. There's no other way to emphasize quoted text and keep it inline with the rest of the text. I never thought it was a problem since inline-code doesn't receive any syntax-highlighting and looks very similar to any quoted text (except for being inline). I've opened up a [discussion on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262463/quoted-text-inline-with-the-rest-using-code-tags-is-bad-why), I'd love for you to check it out

Comment: "The same but monospace" is not what "very similar" means.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I agree with you. That point has been raised in the linked discussion (my suggestion is we whitelist `<q>` so it *would* be very similar)